# Using a Generator with a While loop in Python

Tags: python, generator

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
while next(gen):
    print(value_from_gen)
```

I start with this list
`x=[1,2,3,4,5]`

Then I make a generateor to return the values
`g = ({i:i*2} for i in x`)

When I try:

```
while val = next(g):
    print(val)
```

I get:

```
File "main.py", line 6
    while val = next(g):
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I try:

```
while next(g):
    print(next())
```

It skips some values and I get the error:

```
{2: 4}
{4: 8}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(next(g))
StopIteration
```

when I try:

```
v= -1
while v is not None:
    v=next(g)
    print(v)
```

I get all the values but still get the error:

```
{1: 2}
{2: 4}
{3: 6}
{4: 8}
{5: 10}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
     v=next(g)
StopIteration
```

When I try:

```
for v in g:
    print(v)
```

I get the correct result:

```
{1: 2}
{2: 4}
{3: 6}
{4: 8}
{5: 10}
```

However, I am wondering if this is equivalent to calling `next(g)` and does it keep the laziness benefit of the generator?

Also I am wondering if it is impossible to do this with an actual *while loop*?

Comment: ```while val = next(g):``` needs to be ```while val == next(g):```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Why wouldn't `for v in g: print(v)` work?

Comment: @BuddyBobIII no, OP is trying to assign the output of `next(g)` to `val`, not compare them

Comment: Ok, well that's where the error's coming from. If OP knows that is the error, why post it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [@Brad Martsberger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67248998/1075282), you may pass `False` to default parameter of [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function too:

```
while element:= next(g, False):
    print(element)
```

Answer (score 2):

The forloop version preserves the laziness of the generator and this would be the pythonic version of achieving what you ask in this question.

If you would like to try to force this into a while loop you can do

```
try:
    element = next(g)
    while True:
        print(element)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

If you don't like the try/except you can use a default value in the next call

```
element = next(g, None)
while element is not None:
    print(element)
```

But, this will break if `None` is a valid entry in your generator. You have to use something as your default value that can't be in your generator sequence.

Comment: `while element:= next(g, None):` in second case would work

Comment: I think you want `while (element := next(g, None)) is not None:` in case your generator can yield other falsey results like empty string, empty list, etc. Also need to have python 3.8 or later to use `:=`

Answer (score 1):

1. Remember the assignment expression (:=) was introduced in Python 3.8
2. You don't call `next()` explicitly, the for loop is what you want, and it does keep the laziness of the generator.
3. To implement with a while loop, I think you should use `try/except StopIteration`, but there is no point, just use the for loop,

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
g = ({i: i*2} for i in x)
```

StopIteration exception raised when no element left in generator to iterate over.
You may intend to use Walrus Assignment [check here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)

```
try:
    while val := next(g): # walurs assignment added in Python3.8
        print(val)
except StopIteration:
    # StopIteration exception raised when no element left in generator to iterate over
    pass
```

`next()` being call twice

```
try:
    # This is totaly invalid syntax, because `next()` being call twise so you will have alternate number printed in console
    while next(g):
        #print(next()) # incorrect syntax
        print(next(g)) # correct syntax but `next()`calling twice
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

It is correct but just you needed to apply exception handling. Also, better to use pythonic way as @Bard mentioned

```
try:
    v = -1
    while v is not None:
        v = next(g)
        print(v)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```